# Wordpress Avada: How To Create A Multi-Row Column

Tags: wordpress, grid-system

Using Avada to create a WordPress website, I'm trying to create a column layout like the following picture:

[image]

Avada does have a [nice grid system](https://avada.theme-fusion.com/columns/), but I cant seem to find any documentation showing how I can achieve this fairly simple quest.
At the moment column 2 is pushing column 3 and 4 down.

Any suggestions to how this is implemented?